# Anyway to dynamically set text in an asp:FileUpload?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

When the user selects an item from a dropdownlist containing image names, I would like the FileUpload text box to be filled with a message I program such as "Replace this image with..." How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the nature of the control, for security reasons you cannot manipulate it beyond some styling.

What you can do, however, is use a Flash or Silverlight based upload control.  Or put your desired message in a label above the file input.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about a label, but I was just wondering if there was another way besides making another control.

Answer (score 2):

Security restrictions in certain browsers (IE at least) prevent you from being able to actually set the text of an `<input type="file" />` element, which is what the FileUpload ASP.NET control renders.

I am on a project where we are trying to manipulate the appearance of file upload elements, and it's proving to be quite difficult to do in a cross-browser-compliant manner. I suggest looking at flash-based solutions such as [Uploadify](http://uploadify.com), which is more customizable.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.  The < input type="file" /> is part of the browser chrome.  Some browsers don't show any text at all, so any solution would not be robust. As Bryan suggests, use a < label >.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, there is no way to directly change the text of the file name box, but what you can do is create a label and use positioning to make sure the label appears directly above the uploader.

```
<span runat="server" id="SelectedFileSpan" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 12px">
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="FileNameLabel"></asp:Label>
</span>
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="FileUploader" />
```

Then set the text of the label.